# Animating height of fabricjs rect object decreasing from top instead of bottom

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I've mocked up an MCVE that demonstrates the problem. If you click on the red square then it'll gradually decrease in size (over roughly ~10 seconds) to nothing and then get removed.

However, the animation is bottom up rather than the desired top down.

Is there a way to do this using the standard fabricjs `.animate` method?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.2/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        canvas = new fabric.Canvas('test');

        canvas.observe('mouse:down', function(e) {
            e.target.animate('height', 0, {
                onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
                duration: 10000,
                onComplete: function() { 
                    e.target.remove();                    
                    canvas.renderAll();
                }
            });
        });

        var rect = new fabric.Rect({
            top : 100,
            left : 100,
            width : 200,
            height : 200,
            fill : 'red',
            lockUniScaling: true,
            lockRotation: true,
            hasControls: false
        });

        canvas.add(rect);
        canvas.renderAll();
    });

</script>
<title>Test Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="test" height="1000" width="1000"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
canvas.observe('mouse:down', function (e) {
    if (!e.target)
        return;
    e.target.animate('height', 0, {
        onChange : canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
        duration : 10000,
        onComplete : function () {
            e.target.remove();
            canvas.renderAll();
        }
    });
    //It is suitable if you know initial height... 
    e.target.animate('top', 300, {// initialHeight(100) + initialTop(200) 
        duration : 10000,
        onChange : canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
    });
});
```

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/u665wnq1/1/)

[example 2](https://jsfiddle.net/u665wnq1/3/)

This method is not optimal, but it works!
Need to do custom animate that will change *height* and *top*.